Does 'offset' in this sentence mean the opposite of 'onset'?

Nothing the dogs did could affect the onset, the offset, the duration, or the intensity of the shocks.

In the dictionary definition for 'offset', the only meaning I found that relates to the sentence was

a small deviation or bias in a voltage or current

However, I think this doesn't really fit with the sentence since 'intensity' already covers that meaning. So, I though that maybe 'offset' is meant to be by the writer as the opposite of onset (the words appear side by side), but it isn't a dictionary definition.

Could you give the context of the quote? Is this technical or literary? The more general dictionary defintion of offset is "A things set off against another as equivalent or compensation". The offset of the shocks could mean how far away they were in distance or time from each other or from the refernece point / time. You are right that offset is not the opposite of onset.

@timchessish: But it is the opposite of "onset" (as a later "back-formation"). Full OED offset definition 11: (1932–) Chiefly Medicine and Physiology. Cessation or termination (of a condition, action, stimulus, etc.). Opposed to onset.

Merriam-Webster offers  "cessation" as one of the meanings of the noun offset.
“Offset.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offset. Accessed 29 Apr. 2024.
It is a specialized scientific use of the word that would trip up many readers.

The brain response to sudden onsets has been extensively studied... In contrast to this wealth of knowledge, the brain responses to abrupt and unexpected offsets have been investigated far less. The imbalance between studies of neural responses to onsets and offsets is surprising, given that offsets can also reflect environmental events demanding swift and potentially life-saving behavioral responses: for example, the sudden dimming of light intensity can reflect a predating hawk (and in fact triggers freezing behavior in chicks; Hébert et al. 2019). Accordingly, one might hypothesize that the brain responses to both onsets and offsets reflect the functioning of a common neural system devoted to the detection of, and appropriate reaction to, abrupt intensity changes of any kind (i.e., regardless of their direction or the sensory modality in which they occur).
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9113248/

P.S. There the word "direction" is being used as a proxy for a physical scale that corresponds to intensity of the stimulus, from 0 to some maximum. Moving leftward (or downward) on the axis towards zero is to move in the offset "direction". Grammarians do the same sort of thing when they talk about "left" and "right" in respect to an utterance.

Is this a specifically American use? It's certainly not in Chambers

No, it's a scientific usage.

@timchessish I've added an example.

even in that context, not being a specialist in this area, I would have assumed offset meant variations from the normal signal rather than cessation. I would have expected Chambers to have that usage if it was BrE in this specific context, they are usually pretty thorough. I can see that in your AmE dictionary reference though.

@timchessish "variations from the normal signal" misses the point of the specific example provided.  The example is "the sudden dimming of light intensity". When the light goes out (sudden dimming) the light  suddenly ceases. The paragraph goes on to speak of "onsets and offsets" and "abrupt changes of any kind ... regardless of their direction".  But there's a parallelism being set up: "direction" of "intensity changes" would refer, as I say in the P.S., to either an increase from a base level (the onset "direction") or a decrease from a base level (the offset "direction").

I can see that in some techincal areas I now need to be aware that offset could have a meaning other than the one you would expect in everyday usage. I think I would have misunderstood the brain response example you give. I would have wrongly read "onsets and offsets" as "starts and consequent fluctuations".

@timchessish   I would not have gotten it right either until I went to the NIH site and looked at how the word offset was being used in studies there.
